# Guarantateed minimum size/range of C data types

Tags: c, variables

I have found varying answers to this question, and I know there must be one definitive answer. What is the minimum allocated memory size of the four main data types in C? `int`, `double`, `float`, and `char` are what I'm thinking of. Do the `signed` or `unsigned` types alter the size in any way?

Comment: sizeof(variable);

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of close reason and should be reopened.

Comment: @Steven: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types seems to have the information you seek.

Comment: A *very* related question about C++ data types [size of int, long, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sizeof(variable)`:

As an example running this on my local machine:

```
sizeof (char)   = 1
sizeof (double) = 8
sizeof (float)  = 4
sizeof (int)    = 4
sizeof (long)   = 4
sizeof (long long)  = 8
sizeof (short)  = 2
sizeof (void *) = 4
```

Note: the values you get may be determined by OS/Compiler/CPU architecture.

Comment: Sizes are platform and compiler specific.

Comment: @Toon - yeah he can still use the sizeof operator to determine them himself.

Comment: Yup, sizeof is safe. But the fixed values can be confusing.

Comment: @DarrenDavies Unfortunately your posting does not indicate that the values you published are only examples. And that's exactly the information that is important here.

Answer (score 9):

ANSI C defines the following sizes for the various primitive data types.

- char

  - minimum signed range: -128 .. 127
  - minimum unsigned range: 0 .. 255
  - can be larger, but regardless of size, sizeof(char) == 1
  - sizeof(unsigned char) == 1
- short

  - minimum signed range: -32768 .. 32767
  - minimum unsigned range: 0 .. 65535
  - can be larger
- long

  - minimum signed range: -2147483648 .. 2147483647
  - minimum unsigned range: 0 .. 4294967295
  - can be larger
- int

  - must have, at a miminum, the same range as a short
  - can have the same range as a long
  - cannot have a range larger than a long
  - short <= int, and int <= long, but short < long

There are a bunch more rules for floats and doubles, but generally, the range of a float is <= the range of a double (for modern machines---float is 4 bytes, double is 8).

Answer (score 2):

Only `char` is guaranteed to be `1` byte by the standard.
Rest of the types have implementation defined sizes.

Comment: Indeed, but be aware that 1 byte may not be an octet. There are platforms where bytes are 32 bits wide.

Answer (score 2):

> Do the signed or unsigned types alter the size in any way?

No. It only affects the range of data held. See example below for short data type ( 2 bytes).

- signed   −32,768 to   +32,767
- unsigned 0   to   65,535

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. I refer you to C99 6.2.5. And the [Wikipedia C data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) article is fine.

- char is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set.  It is not a byte (as defined by 8 bits), and a good way of thinking about it is that it is the minimum addressable/allocatable unit (MAU), as you write in your question, but on some systems is not a byte.
- ints are sort of interesting. I think they are supposed to hold a minimum of 2^15-1 (16 bits), but I can't find it in C99 at the moment. In newer versions of the standard I believe they are actually defined as a minimum of 32 bits, because so many people assume that they are.  But in general you must assume that they are implementation defined in terms of MAUs (`sizeof()`).  Not only that, but the specification allows for padding bits (such as for error correction).  So, on an 8 bit character system, if the `sizeof(int)` is 4, the maximum int is not necessarily 2^31-1, because the specification allows some of those bits to be used as "padding."  Thus the only way to know for sure is to use `limits.h`!
- float/double are also implementation defined although double is always bigger than a float.  Commonly these are defined by the implementation as compatible with the IEEE-754 specification (which require a minimum of 32 and 64 bits respectively), but C99 does not require it.  But if your char size is 32 bits, then the sizeof(float) may be only 1.
- signed/unsigned do not change the size.

For these reasons `<stdint.h>` is one of the most important new additions to the C language.  Prior to that it was extremely difficult to write cross-platform code.

Answer (score -1):

Write a little test program and see for yourself:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(char) );
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(int) );
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(unsigned char) );
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(unsigned int) );
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(double) );
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(float) );
    return 0;
}
```

"int, float, double" is platform-dependent ( 16, 32, 64).  sign does not affect size, only interpretation.

Comment: `%zu`, not `%d`. `sizeof` returns `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: It's important to notice that the result will differ depending on whatever platform you compile for. I suggest you add this to your answer, Leor.